# KornShell Boolean Conditional Logic

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I am a little confused with this KornShell (ksh) script I am writing, mostly with booleans and conditionals.

So the first part of my script I have `catme` and `wcme` both set to either `true` or `false`. This part is working fine, as I have tried `echo`ing them and they produce the expected results. Later on, I have this code:

```
if [[ $catme ]] ; then
    some commands
fi
```

And I repeat this with `wcme`. However, unexpectedly, no matter what `wcme` and `catme` are, the commands inside my `if` statement are executed.

Is this a syntax error? I have tried `[[ $catme -eq true ]]` but that does not seem to work either. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`test` and `[` are the same thing.  You need to get rid of the `test` command from your if statement, so it would look like this:

```
if $catme; then
    some commands
fi
```

Type `man test` to get more info.

For example:

```
$ v=true  
$ $v
$ if $v; then
>   echo "PRINTED"
> fi
PRINTED

$ v=false
$ if $v; then
>   echo "PRINTED"
> fi
$
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also try the trial and error method:

```
if [[ true ]]; then echo +true; else echo -false; fi
+true
if [[ false ]]; then echo +true; else echo -false; fi
+true
if [[ 0 ]]; then echo +true; else echo -false; fi
+true
if [[ -1 ]]; then echo +true; else echo -false; fi
+true
if (( -1 )); then echo +true; else echo -false; fi
+true
if (( 0 )); then echo +true; else echo -false; fi
-false
if (( 1 )); then echo +true; else echo -false; fi
+true
if [[ true == false ]]; then echo +true; else echo -false; fi
-false
if [[ true == true ]]; then echo +true; else echo -false; fi
+true
if true; then echo +true; else echo -false; fi
+true
if false; then echo +true; else echo -false; fi
-false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `[[ $catme == true ]]` instead.

Or better still, gahooa's answer is pretty good.